Basis of a subspace in $\mathbb{C}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$
Suppose that $W=\{ (z_1,z_2):\bar{z}_1=-z_2 \}\subset \mathbb{C}^2$ where $\mathbb{C}^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. I am wondering if a basis of $W$ would be
$\beta_W=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}-i \\-i\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$
and a basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$ that contains $\beta_W$ would be $\beta_{\mathbb{C}^2}=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}-i \\-i\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1 \\i\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}i \\1\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$.
With the sets specified, would $span(\beta_W)=W$ and would $span(\beta_{\mathbb{C}^2})=\mathbb{C}^2$
Is this correct? Any feedback would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

What do you mean by the basis. As it usually happens, $W$ has infinitely many bases.

Sorry, I should have specified. I mean a set of vectors such that $span(\beta_W)=W$. I'm wondering if the set that I mentioned achieves that.

What has that to do with what I wrote? Yes $\beta_W$ is a basis of $W$.  But it is not the basis since there are infinitely many of such bases.

Aside from needing to change "the basis" to "a basis" due to lack of uniqueness of bases, this is correct, yes.

I edited the original question. I understand it now - thank you @Lavender and @JoséCarlosSantos!
